# VS 2015 CTP - JavaScript Language Run time crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm getting the following error as soon as I open any JavaScript file in Visual Studio 2015.

> The JavaScript language service has encountered an error and has been shut down.  Please save your changes, exit, and restart Visual Studio.

There are no error in the output window for the JavaScript Language Service. I'm not sure where to even start debugging...

I've reset VS setting to default, removed web essentials, and removed resharper and it made no difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and have no solution but a lame workaround.  My app is primarily TypeScript, not javascript, so I don't have to edit javascript files, but whenever they open through debugging or when I'm looking at javascript libraries such as JQuery, VS2015 will crash.  What I did was change the default edit for javascript files using the "Open with" functionality.  I selected the JSON editor rather than the source code editor.  If you have to edit javascript files, I'd recommend doing it externally until they sort this out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ended up completely uninstalling and re-installing to fix the issue.